# how to change the alternate rows background color of a GWT cellList

Tags: gwt

is there a possibility of changing the alternate row color  of a cellList on mouse over 
(just like CellTable)?

Thanks

I am trying this

```
      private CellList<EmployerJobs> clJobs ; 
        EmployerJobCell jobCell = new EmployerJobCell();
    clJobs = new CellList<EmployerJobs>(jobCell);

      clJobs.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<EmployerJobs>() {
    public String getStyleNames(EmployerJobs row, int rowIndex) {

                if (rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                    return "cellListEvenItem";
                } else {
                    return "cellListOddItem ";
                }
            }

    });
```

but at the above line :

```
                       clJobs.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<EmployerJobs>()
```

it says :

```
                The method setRowStyles(new RowStyles<EmployerJobs>(){}) is undefined for the type CellList<EmployerJobs>
```

Comment: [Here is all styles of CellList.](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.css?r=9687)

Comment: its look very sinple , but how will use this , can i simply assign style name to css , or i need to do some thing more in my code to get this style working

Comment: In your stylesheet just override needed style. For example: `.cellListKeyboardSelectedItem {
  background: red;
}
`

Comment: i am trying to create my style , but its giving error , i have edited my question , kindly have a look , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better create your own css file based on gwt's default and copy [CellList styles](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.css?r=9687) to your newly created css file and change all you need. You also need to exclude gwt default css from your_module.gwt.xml and put there your newly created

Comment: The question is how to change mouse over style. Any ideas which style response for this in that link (which you coppied from my comment)?